# How can I attach a patch to a nylon backpack?

Tags: hiking, backpacks

I recently got my new Osprey Atmos 65, and I really want to attach some patches that I bought online. Will normal iron patches work or can I sew them on instead?

Will it damage the backpack?

Answer (score 4):

**Iron-on**

Be **very** careful of iron-on - nylon melts! You have to get the temperature right. I wouldn't be confident that the patch would hold as the rucksack flexes, though I guess that depends on the quality of the adhesive you use.

**Sewing**

Sewing will puncture the fabric and allow a little moisture through. You could mitigate this by applying silicone seam sealant to your stitch-holes on the inside of the pack. Not a bad solution, and less prone to disaster than iron-on.

**Bonding**

If the patch is made of nylon, you could bond it on for a reliable solution.

1. Purchase a silicone seam sealer like McNETT SilNet, or any 100% silicone sealant from the hardware store.
2. Spread the sealant thinly on the back of your patch
3. Stick the patch to the pack
4. Apply pressure evenly over the patch with something heavy
5. Leave overnight for the bond to cure.

This will only work reliably with nylon. If the patch is polyester or some natural fabric you'd probably be better to sew it on and seal the holes.

Comment: Also note that depending on where you want to iron patch on the pack, ironing it properly may be pretty hard because you might not be able to get a nice flat surface underneath it.